# View Stroke not working in Android above lollipop

Tags: android, view, line

> Have implemented the View to draw the line its working below kitkat version and it's not working in lollipop and Marshmallow devices.

Below is my code:

```
 <View
        android:id="@+id/vDottedLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/sixteen_dp_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/sixteen_dp_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted"
        android:layerType="software" />
```

> XML file for color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke
    android:height="2dp"
    android:color="#000"
    android:dashGap="3dp"
    android:dashWidth="8dp" />

</shape>
```

And also tried adding `android:layerType="software"` and `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`
 and false as well. Any hint to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

create drawable file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#999999"
    android:dashGap="5dp"
    android:dashWidth="2dp" />
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<size
    android:width="2dp"
    android:height="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Your View :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dash"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```